# Mixing two tables together

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

db2:

```
id, db1id, text, count_db1
```

db1:

```
id, text
```

db2 above is created by

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`db1id`) AS count_db1 FROM `db2` GROUP BY `db1id` ORDER BY count_db1 DESC
```

so the last column is added and the whole output is sorted descendingly by count_db1.

db1ids are ids of db1. I want to

```
SELECT * FROM db1
```

ordered by the value of count_db1 in db1. If id of db1 is not existant in db2 as db1id it should be added to the end of the list(ie assigned a value of 0 for count_db1).

example:

```
db2:
id, db1id, text, count_db1
1,4,hello,5
2,4,hello,5
3,4,ho,5
5,4,yeah,5
6,4,no,5
4,3,no,1

db1:
id, text
3, yeahright
4, whatever
```

So in db2 db1id 4 occurs 5 times, db1id 3 occurs 1 time. So order the entries of db1 such that id 4 comes before id 3. Result should be:

1. whatever
2. yeahright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` with a `COUNT` should do what you want;

```
SELECT db1.*
FROM db1
LEFT JOIN db2
  ON db1.id=db2.db1id
GROUP BY db1.id, db1.text
ORDER BY COUNT(db2.id) DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/021cd6/6).

Comment: you beat me by 10 sec **AND** made an sqlfiddle! +1

Comment: How do I create this by myself next time?

Comment: @user2348735 Quick explanation; a `db1 LEFT JOIN db2` means that the id must exist in `db1`, but not necessarily in `db2`. A normal `JOIN` wwould instead remove all rows that don't exist in both. The `GROUP BY` says that you want a result per `db1.id`/`db1.text` combination, and the `ORDER BY COUNT(db2.id) DESC` orders by the number of rows in `db2` that are in each group `GROUP BY` just created. `DESC` just means descending order, from high to low.

Answer (score 0):

i did not test this. but maybe it works for you:

```
SELECT db1.text FROM db1 INNER JOIN `db2` ON db2.db1id = db1.id 
GROUP BY `db1id` 
ORDER BY (COUNT(`db1id`)) DESC
```

Edit: Since you want to see the "empty" records as well you should use `LEFT JOIN` as pointed out by the other posters.

```
SELECT db1.text FROM db1 LEFT JOIN `db2` ON db2.db1id = db1.id 
GROUP BY db1.id, db1.text 
ORDER BY (COUNT(`db1id`)) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` is preferred on this case because you still want the record on `db1` to be shown on the list even if the `id` doesn't exist on `db2.db1id`.

```
SELECT  a.text
FROM    db1 a
        LEFT JOIN db2 b
            ON a.id = b.db1id
GROUP   BY a.id, a.text
ORDER   BY COUNT(b.db1id) DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00a98/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*added extra records*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b072f/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)